# How to get registration token for FCM push notification for Android?

Tags: android, python, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building an push notification service using https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm

this requires an API_KEY and Registation ID of device to send message.

I have created an app on [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com/) and have got the API_KEY.
Now i have no clue how to get the Registration ID.

Are there dummy app(s) on installation of which it will return registration ID or something like that ?

Comment: cant you create your own android app to generate Device tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I have created an app on console.developers.google.com and have got the API_KEY.*

You'll only be able to get a valid *Server Key* when you create a project in [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com). API Keys (recently) generated in the Developer's Console would not work for GCM (and FCM). From the note in the [docs (under Server Key)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#key):

> Starting from September 2016, you can create new server keys only in the Firebase Console using the Cloud Messaging tab of the Settings panel. Existing projects that need to create a new server key can be imported in the Firebase console without affecting their existing configuration.

---

> *Are there dummy app(s) on installation of which it will return registration ID or something like that?*

You'll have to create your own dummy app where you'll have to call the `getToken()` to generate a Registration token (aka Registration ID). See the [FCM Quickstart in GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging).